# IsolatedStorageException : Could not find file

Tags: unity, android

I'm trying to save/load player data from a file using the persistenceDataPath using the following code:

```
private void Save()
    {
        if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
            data.userExperience = userExperience;
            bf.Serialize (file, data);
            file.Close ();
        }
    }

private void Load() 
{   
    if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
    {   
        FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat ", FileMode.Open);
        PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize (file);
        userExperience = data.userExperience;
        file.Close ();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public int userExperience;
}
```

It works fine if I play the game with Unity Editor. However, on Android, when I try to execute this line of code in Load():

```
FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat ", FileMode.Open);
```

I get this error:
[image]

The file does exist since the code pass through the if(File.Exist...) and it works when I try to access the file from the Save() method.

I really don't know what it could be since the code that open the file in Save() and Load() is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the source of the error.

In the Load() method I was passing the path with a space at the end and that was why on Android it wasn't able to reach the file.

Apparently, when playing from the Unity editor it was still able to access the path even with the space at the end.